# Rounding imprecision when performing area-weighted interpolation of population (discrete) data

Tags: interpolation, population

I guess this is more a conceptual question.

I'm performing area-weighted interpolation between two very granular geometries, and I have three variables: `population_total`, `population_men` and `population_women`. `population total` is the sum of `population_men` and `population_women`.
These geometries are very granular, so I have a few cases where let's say my target geometry got 40% of the area of my source geometry with `population_total = 2` and  `population_men == 1` and `population_women == 1`.
When calculating the population of my target geometry, I would get

- `population_total = 0.4 * 2 = 0.8`
- `population_men = 0.4 * 1 = 0.4`
- `population_women = 0.4 * 1 = 0.4`

I want to round (the data will be available to the general public etc) so I can get an integer for my population estimation. So if I round my variables, I would get `pop_total = 1` and `pop_men = 0` and `pop_women = 0`. The sum doesn't add up.
If I round up, I would get 1 != 1 + 1.

Any tips on how to solve this?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/521566 might be helpful.